# Trigger sort method from an event in Backbone.js

Tags: sorting, backbone.js, comparator

I have a Backbone.js project which uses a comparator function defined in the collection. It sorts items when the page is refreshed, but I am trying to get it to sort when a button is clicked instead of on page refresh. Here is my code:

```
   var Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         title: 'blank',
         rank: ''
     }
 });
 var ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'thingClass',
     template: _.template('<b><button id="remove">X</button> <b><button id="edit">Edit</button> <%= title %>  Rank:<%= rank %></b>'),
     editTemplate: _.template('<input class="name" value="<%= name %>" /><button id="save">Save</button>'),

     events: {
         "click #remove": "deleteItem",
         "click #edit": "editItem",
         "click #save": "saveItem",
     },
     deleteItem: function () {
         console.log('deleted');
         this.model.destroy();
         this.remove();
     },
     editItem: function () {
         console.log('editing');
         this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
     },
     saveItem: function () {
         console.log('saved');
         editTitle = $('input.name').val();
         console.log(editTitle);
         this.model.save({
             title: editTitle
         });
         this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
     },
     render: function () {
         var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
         //console.log (attributes);
         this.$el.append(this.template(attributes));
         return this;
     }
 });
 var ThingsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Thing,
     localStorage: new Store("store-name"),
     comparator: function(thing) {
     return thing.get('rank');
     },
 });

 var thingsList = new ThingsList;
 var ThingsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: $('body'),
     events: {
         'click #add': 'insertItem',
         'click #sort': 'sortItems',
     },
     initialize: function () {
    thingsList.fetch();
    thingsList.toJSON();
         this.render();
         this.collection.on("add", this.renderThing, this);
         this.collection.on("reset", this.clearRender, this);
     },
     insertItem: function (e) {
         newTitle = $('#new-item').val();
         newRank = $('#rank').val();
         newThing = new Thing({
             title: newTitle,
             rank: newRank
         });
         this.collection.add(newThing);
         newThing.save();
         console.log(this.collection.length);
     },

     sortItems: function (e) {
        console.log('clicked sort button');
        this.collection.sort();
        this.$el.detach('.item');
     },

     render: function () {
         _.each(this.collection.models, function (items) {
             this.renderThing(items);
         }, this);

     },
     renderThing: function (items) {
         var thingView = new ThingView({
             model: items
         });
         this.$el.append(thingView.render().el);
     },

     clearRender: function () {
        console.log('clear render called')

         _.each(this.collection.models, function (items) {
             //this.remove();
             this.$el.remove(".thingClass")
             this.renderThing(items);
         }, this);

     },



     test: function (items) {
         console.log('test worked');
     },


 });
 var thingsListView = new ThingsListView({
     collection: thingsList
 });
```

Comment: `Sort()` will invoke a reset event. Subscribe the view to that event and re render the collection

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your collection isn't resorting itself? keep in mind that the order of the models in the collection won't change the order of how they appear on the page if they are already rendered.

I'm guessing that what you are trying to do is resort the items that have already been rendered, to do so you would need re-render your collection. If you are going to do so I would recommend that you cache your views and on a sort detach the associated element from the DOM and reattach them in the correct order.

As an example

```
var ThingsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  _views: {},

  initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind('add', this.add, this);
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this); //sort triggers a reset 
  },

  add: function (thing) {
    var view = new ThingView({model: thing});
    this._views[thing.cid] = view; //use client id of model as key for the views cache
    this.$el.append(view.render().el); 
  },

  render: function() {

    $('li, this.$el).detach(); //detach so that bound events aren't lost
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(thing) {        
        this.$el.append(this.views[thing.cid].el); //get view from cache
    },this);

  },

  sort: function() {
    this.collection.sort();
  }

}

})
```

(a couple of differences from my example code and yours I'm assuming here that the collection view has a 'el' referring to a container 'ul', I also don't show how your triggering the sort (basically something like `thingListView.sort()`;)

Edit: It might not be so obvious from the example code I posted, so I should have mentioned to begin with what @Deeptechtons said that when you sort a collection it [triggers a `reset`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-sort) event

Edit2: If your not interested in caching your views, then the easiest way to remove your current views would probablly be to add a class to the rendered div

```
var ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({
     className: 'thingClass',
   //rest of your thingViewCode
```

Then in your clearRender method just add `$(".thingClass", this.$el).remove();` to the beginning of the method.

Comment: My models are in divs not li's. I've found that if I add      sortItems: function (e) {
        this.render();
     },
then, the list renders in the correct order underneith the existing list. So if I can just work out how to remove the first unsorted version from the screen, I think it will work.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference what your actually using, I was just using that as an example. You can add a class to your container div and use that to detach if you want ('this.$el.detach('.youClass');`).

Comment: I found the previous answers difficult to understand and overly complicated for what I am trying to do, although I appreciate the help. I updated the question to show where I am now. sortItems function of collection view calls sort on collection and detaches class surrounding model. It adds sorted but doesnt remove the original unsorted from the view, which is what I want.

Comment: Is your `clearRender()` method getting called? if you don't care about reusing your existing views then in that method before you rerender just remove the current views from the DOM.

Comment: Yes clearRender() is getting called, and I guess the problem is I dont know the syntax to remove my current views from the DOM. The //this.remove(); removed everything from the page including the input boxes and buttons at the top, and the render after didnt happen. I have the collectionview's el set to body, is that the issue?

Comment: Yes (`this.remove()` removes the view's `el`), but you should be able to work around that, i'll update my answer with some example code.

Comment: I tried what was listed in edit2, it is not removing the views. It does add the class as I can see using "view generated source" in the firefox developer toolbar. The new code is updated in my question above. I have tried it with the this.$el.remove(".thingClass") both before and inside of the _.each statement.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I posted the wrong (jquery) syntax for `remove/detach` it should be `$('.thingView', this.$el).remove();`

Comment: awesome. it was actually $('.thingClass', this.$el).remove(); and it goes before the _.each. It works now. thanks for your help